# Do I have to drop a random slope if I drop the fixed effect in mixed-models for model comparison?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, likelihood-ratio

I'm performing a model comparison using the likelihood ratio test in R with two mixed models fitted with `lme4`.
My model is:

```
fit1 <- lmer(y ~ x * z + (z|id))
```

If I want to compare `fit1` with a model **without** the effect `z` and then compare models with `anova(fit1, fit0)` should I need to remove also the random slope?

```
# Option 1

fit0 <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|id))

# Option 2

fit0 <- lmer(y ~ x + (z|id))

anova(fit1, fit0)
```

My idea is that when dropping a fixed effect I should also remove the random part. However, I guess that removing also the random slopes can somehow influence the test partially hiding the contribution of the fixed effect.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Your intuition is correct - you should remove the random slopes too.

You don't *have* to drop the random slope, but if you don't then you need to be extremely sure that the overall effect of that variable is zero. Recall that random effects are assumed to be normally distributed and can be interpreted as an offset to the global estimate for the relevant variable. So for example, with random intercepts the model will typically estimate a global intercept and then each group for which random intercepts are specified has their own offset from that global intercept. If you remove the global intercept from the model and just fit random intercepts you are saying that the individual intercepts for each group are clustered around zero with a normal distribution. With random slopes it is the same so if you remove the fixed effect without removing the random effect you are assuming that the overall effect for that variable is zero. Since this is hardly ever the case, this is typically not a good idea.

Also, try not to choose which variables you include in your regression model with a likelihood ratio test.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so please consider marking it as the accepted answer. If not, please let us know why. Also, if you haven't already, please consider upvoting it.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your response, my case is very similar to this one. I have a model with an interaction with full random effects. So y = x*z + (x*z|id). The wald test is telling me my fixed effect for the interaction x:z is wildly insiginficant (p = 0.75). However if I use LLR test and drop both the fixed and random effect for the interaction, it tells me it is highly significant. What should I do? If I drop only the fixed and keep the random it's still significant. I think it's only the fixed component that is insignificant but it would be weird to keep the random slope in.

Comment: @teeniv is this a model containing only the interaction as fixed effects ? What about the main effects ? It's hardly ever a good idea to fit a model with an interaction but without main effects.

Comment: @RobertLong sorry, the formatting didn't help. This is a generalised linear mixed effects  model (log link and gaussian variance structure) with main and interaction effects, and full random effects. So y = x + z + x:z + (x + z + x:z|id). Wald Z test says x:z fixed effect is not significant, but not sure how to test this correctly using LLR tests.

Comment: @teeniv Ahh OK ! Do you have a theoretical reason to expect there to be a meaningful interaction ? I think you need to post a new question about this. Feel free to @ me in this thread with a link, and I will try to take a look (@ doesn't work if the person is not already involved so don't @ me in the new post unless I have commented or posted an answer)

Comment: @RobertLong Theoretically it does make sense to have an interaction, as different values of x can sensitise how y changes over z. Using a log link weakens the strength of the interaction by a lot however. I have run the same model on 4 different sets of data that are similar. In 3 of them the interaction is statistically significant but it's coefficient is very very small. For uniformity I would like to present the 4th model also with the interaction present, but I'm wondering if it would be wrong to do so if it isn't statistically significant. I hesitate to make a new post, but perhaps I will

Comment: @RobertLong I just re-read your answer to this question and may have solved it myself. Since my coefficient for x:z is very very small, nearly 0, I understand why it can make sense to run the model with only random and no fixed effects for x:z, and why those random effects can be significant. The individual offsets help for each id, but the fixed effect doesn't do much. Does that make sense?

Comment: @teeniv yes that does make sense - well, at least it is plausible. Another point is whether you conducted a power analysis to determine your sample size? Do you have sufficient statistical power to detect the effect size you are interested in ? Honestly I think you should ask a new question about this, as there are a number of considerations, and we are abusing the SE system by discussing this in comments.